# Is it possible to two way bind variables between nested isolate scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, isolate-scope

Consider the nested directives below. I have been trying to bind variables between the isolate scopes of nested directives and have been unable to achieve a two way binding.

In the example I want the `outerPower` to bind to the `innerPower` and change when the `innerPower` number increments.

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hally9k/sqea6Ln7/

```
testApp.directive('innerDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
           innerPower: '&'
        },
        template: '<div><p>Inner Power = {{innerPower}}</p>' +
            '<button ng-click="increment();">Power up!</button>' +
            '</div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
           $scope.increment = function() {
                ++$scope.innerPower;
           }
        }
    };
});

testApp.directive('outerDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {

        },
        template: '<div><p>Outer Power = {{outerPower}}</p>' +
            '<div inner-directive inner-power="outerPower"></div>' +
        '</div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
           $scope.outerPower = 0;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bi-directional binding, you need to use `=` for the scope variable. `&` should only be used when your directive needs to execute a function in the parent scope.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabpqfp4/)

```
scope: {
   innerPower: '='
},
```

Comment: What to do when 2 answers are same? Mine is 21 seconds later, but i didn't see your answer while was writing mine, so should i delete or leave it as it is?

Comment: Not sure :p I think leaving it is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just change single line

```
scope: {
     innerPower: '=' //instead of &
}
```